# When compiling, I receive the error: "unreachable statement". How can I fix the issue?

Tags: java, object, methods

```
public double Convertir(double Number) {
    Number = nombre;
    while ((Number - 365) >= 0) {
        annee += 1;   //this calculates the number of years    
    }
    return annee;
    double nombreSemaine = Number - (annee * 365);
    while ((nombreSemaine - 7) >= 0) {
        semaine = semaine + 1;
    }//this calculates the number of weeks
    return semaine;
    double nombreJour = Number - (annee * 365) - (semaine * 7);
    nombreJour = jour;
    return jour;
}
```

With this code I am trying to convert a number written by the user,
which are days, into the number of years that it makes, the number of
weeks and the number of days. for example, number 365 should return 1
year 0 weeks 0 days.

Comment: Anything after `return annee;` will not be executed.

Comment: please, post formatted code!

Comment: How are you expecting "1 year 0 weeks 0 days" to be represented in just one `double` value?

Comment: You cannot return multiple values from a method - you need to create a `Bean` to wrap your 3 values.

Comment: Also, what is nombre? And please rename variables so you follow Java conventions.

Comment: It's usually helpful to post the error message you receive, so we don't have to guess what's going on.

Comment: Also, this is a question that could be answered easily by searchin the internet.

Comment: For some more on `return` see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html. In fact, see all of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html.

Answer (score 5):

`return annee;` returns `annee` so anything after this expression in the method won't get executed.

Perhaps you could return an `Array` instead:

```
public double[] Convertir(double Number) {
    Number = nombre;
    double[] all = new double[3];
    while ((Number - 365) >= 0) {
        annee += 1;   //this calculates the number of years    
    }
    all[0] = annee;
    double nombreSemaine = Number - (annee * 365);
    while ((nombreSemaine - 7) >= 0) {
        semaine = semaine + 1;
    }//this calculates the number of weeks
    all[1] = semaine;
    double nombreJour = Number - (annee * 365) - (semaine * 7);
    nombreJour = jour;
    all[2] = jour;

    return all
}
```

or something similar. An `ArrayList` would probably be better...but it's the same general concept.

Answer (score 5):

The code below `return annee;` won't be executed.

It looks like you want to return 3 values. You can only return 1 value, a `double` in this case.

**Solution 1 (Global variables):**

```
int annee, semaine, jour; //global variables

public void Convertir(int Number) { //I guess number should be an Int too, unless it's possible to pass 567.28 days...
    //Number = nombre; Useless since this is a parameter
    annee = (int)(Number/365);
    semaine = (int)((Number - annee * 365)/7);
    jour = Number - annee * 365 - semaine * 7;
}
```

**Solution 2 (return an array):**

```
public int[] Convertir(int Number) { //I guess number should be an Int too, unless it's possible to pass 567.28 days...
    //Number = nombre; Useless since this is a parameter
    int[] anneeSemaineJour = new int[3];
    anneeSemaineJour[0] = (int)(Number/365);
    anneeSemaineJour[1] = (int)((Number - anneeSemaineJour[0] * 365)/7);
    anneeSemaineJour[2] = Number - anneeSemaineJour[0] * 365 - anneeSemaineJour[1] * 7;

    return anneeSemaineJour;
}
```

**You will then use it like this (Solution 2):**

```
int[] resultat = convertir(822); // convertir(nombre) in your case I guess
System.out.println("Annee = " + resultat[0] + " Semaine = " + resultat[1] + " Jour = " + resultat[2]);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you have code (including another `return`) after a `return` statement. A `return` statement stops the function at that place and returns the value. Anything after that is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code suffers from many problems.

Beside all what other have said (**Everything below `return` won't be executed**) you should be careful with your `while` loops, they are infinite loops:

```
while ((Number - 365) >= 0) {
        annee += 1;   //this calculates the number of years    
}
```

If `Number - 365 >= 0` then you're inside the `while` and you're adding `1` to `annee`, and this will not stop the loop since `Number - 365 >= 0` will continue to be satisfied.

Same thing with your second loop.

Answer (score 0):

"return" exits the method. If you want to return all of them (years, months, days) you can use an array. Your code had generally many mistakes, and similar operations were done on nombre (or Number as you had it) multiple times. I have tried to make to code runnable.

```
public double[] Convertir(double nombre) {
    double[] yearsWeeksAndDays = new double[3];
    double annee = 0;
    double semaine = 0;
    while (nombre >= 365) {
        annee += 1;   //this calculates the number of years
        nombre -= 365;    
    }
    yearsWeeksAndDays[0] = annee;
    while (nombre >= 7) {
        semaine = semaine + 1;
        nombre -= 7;
    }//this calculates the number of weeks
    yearsWeeksAndDays[1] = semaine;
    yearsWeeksAndDays[2] = nombre;
    return yearsWeeksAndDays;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap you 3 return values into a `class` and return that. Something like this ought to work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convertir(365));
    System.out.println(convertir(366.5));
    System.out.println(convertir(456));

}

static class Duration {

    int years;
    int weeks;
    double days;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return years + " years, " + weeks + " weeks and " + days + " days.";
    }
}

public static Duration convertir(double total) {
    final Duration duration = new Duration();
    duration.years = (int) (total / 365);
    total = total % 365;
    duration.weeks = (int) (total / 7);
    total = total % 7;
    duration.days = total;
    return duration;
}
```

Output:

```
1 years, 0 weeks and 0.0 days.
1 years, 0 weeks and 1.5 days.
1 years, 13 weeks and 0.0 days.
```

Obviously it needs a little translation but French isn't my strong suit.

Answer (score -1):

its throwing unrreachable code because compiler knows that when the controll reaches that return statement, then it would return and no more code would be executed.To solve this, what you could do is, either put the return statement in a condition block like i have shown below, but again  this program wont return u the result you wanted. it will return only the year. if you want the entire result ie. number of years + number of weeks + number of  days i would suggest you to make the entire answer to a single string and return.

```
public double Convertir(double Number) {
        // Number = nombre;
        double annee = 0;
        double semaine = 0;
        double jour = 0;
        while ((Number - 365) >= 0) {
            annee += 1; // this calculates the number of years
        }
        if (annee > 0) {
            return annee;
        }
        double nombreSemaine = Number - (annee * 365);
        while ((nombreSemaine - 7) >= 0) {
            semaine = semaine + 1;
        }// this calculates the number of weeks
        if (semaine > 0)
            return semaine;

        double nombreJour = Number - (annee * 365) - (semaine * 7);
        nombreJour = jour;
        return jour;
    }
```

Comment: You say "i would suggest you to make the entire answer to a single string and return." but your example doesnt do that.